# save field inputs to sessionStorage for each add with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, local-storage

I have a form that allows users to dynamically add fields for each project requirement. I want to save their inputs to localStorage to populate a drop down box on the next page. I have each indexed number populating but every value afterwards populates with the very first value entered. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

**Updated** code that returns first 2 indvidual inputs but not additional ones*

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
            var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
            var wrapper         = $(".moreReqs"); //Fields wrapper
            var add_button      = $(".addReq-btn"); //Add button ID
            // var inputValue      = $
            var x = 1; //initlal text box count
            $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
                e.preventDefault();
                if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                    x++; //text box increment
                      $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group" id="req_name" name="req_name">' + x + '.{{ newReqs.req_name(class_='form-control', id='reqInput(x)') }}<a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a></div>');//add input box
                var userInput = document.getElementById("reqInput(x)").value;
sessionStorage.setItem(x, userInput );
                    };
            });
            $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
            });

        });
```

[form inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnEKM.png)
[form values saved to storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBFQ0.png)

Comment: `var userInput = document.getElementById("reqInput").value;` is always grabbing the same field.  Should it be using `'reqInput' + x` (or something) as the ID?

Comment: that adds reqInput to the number. i'm trying to get the value for each number. thank you for the suggestion tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the advice from Mike B. I modified by js to include separate IDs.  I then added a button that will set the values into localStorage.  The variables are looped through to be displayed on the next page.

**Adding separte IDs:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper         = $(".moreReqs"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".addReq-btn"); //Add button ID
  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
      if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group" id="req_name" name="req_name">' + x + '.{{ newReqs.req_name(class_='form-control', id="reqInput' + x +'") }}<a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a></div>');//add input box
      };
   });
   $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
     e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    });

 });
```

**button to set and Call the array**

```
function getValue() {
  var values = $("[id^=reqInput]").map(function(){
   return this.value;
    }).get();

    console.log(values);
    sessionStorage.setItem("reqs", JSON.stringify(values));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group" id="req_name" name="req_name">' + x + '.{{ newReqs.req_name(class_='form-control', id='reqInput') }}<a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a></div>');//add input box
```

This line is creating input boxes that all have the id "reqInput".
In HTML, you can't have the same ID on more than one element, so this line:

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("reqInput").value;
```

...is always giving you the value of the first element (the subsequent ones are invalid).

If you append the number (x) for each input (making it `"reqInput1"`, `"reqInput2"`, etc.), both when you append them and when you retrieve the value, I think you'll be good since there won't be any shared IDs (though you will need to account for what happens if someone deletes any input other than the very last one!)

The updated section of the code would be something like:

```
if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
    x++; //text box increment
    var inputId = "reqInput" + x;
    $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group" id="req_name" name="req_name">' + x + '.{{ newReqs.req_name(class_='form-control', id='???') }}<a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-fw fa-lg"></i></a></div>');//add input box
    var userInput = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
};
```

I'm not quite sure what you're using in the append line where it says `{{ newReqs.req_name(class_='form-control', id='reqInput(x)') }}`, but the end result is that you want to use the value of the `inputId` variable (which will be "reqInput1" or "reqInput2" or so on) as the id for the input box.

Comment: Thank you! That gets me part way there. it saves the first two values but not additional ones

Comment: Ah, I see... I meant append the _value_ of x.  :)  Update coming shortly...